# Cannot use slotLabelFormat in Full Calendar version 5.6.0

Tags: typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using Full calendar version 5.6.0 using Typescript scheduler.
I am trying to use slotLabelFomrat in it but everytime webpart loads it gives error "context.cmdFormatter is not a function".

using slotLabelFormat I want to modify time format how time is diaplyed in resourceTimelinePlugin from 9AM to 9:00.

Any help would be much appreciated?

Regards
Deeksha

Comment: Can you supply enough code to reproduce the problem please. It's not obvious what would cause that issue.

Comment: Below solution works for me  views={{
                resourceTimelineDay: {
                  type: 'resourceTimeline',
                  // duration: { weeks: 2 },
                  //slotDuration: {days: 1},
                  slotLabelFormat: [
                    { hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', omitZeroMinute: false, hour12: false }, // top level of text
                    // lower level of text
                  ]
                },

Comment: Please add it as an answer below, not a comment. then people can find it in searches, and can give you upvotes if they found it useful. That way, everyone benefits! Glad you solved it though